# reactjs map and css class toggle

Tags: reactjs

```
      <div>
    {this.props.data.map((res, index) => {
      return (<div key={index}>
        <div>
          <span>{response.testData}</span>
<a key={index} onClick={() => this.showExtraLine(index)}><span className={`btn-green ${this.state.showExtraLine ? 'active' : ''}`}></span></a>
          { this.state.showExtraLine ? <span>
            {res.abc[0].def}
          </span> : '' }
        </div>
      </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
 showExtraLine(e){
    this.setState({
      showExtraLine: !this.state. showExtraLine,
    });
  }
```

Need to toggle the {res.abc[0].def} part on click of anchor - toggle works, but not sure how to handle toggling only the corresponding span - right now it is hiding all the rows..how to handle css toggle when using .map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your state variable, you are using a single state variable and printing the `<span>` on the basis of state of that variable.
Instead of that use an array in state `showExtraLine = []`,
in showExtraLine() function you are passing index, use that index to toggle only that element.

Try this it should work:

```
{this.props.data.map((res, index) => {
  return (<div key={index}>
    <div>
      <span>{response.testData}</span>
      <a key={index} onClick={() => this.showExtraLine(index)}><span className={`btn-green ${!this.state.showExtraLine[index] ? 'active' : ''}`}></span></a>
      { !this.state.showExtraLine[index] ? 
         <span>{res.abc[0].def}</span> 
      : '' }
    </div>
  </div>
  );
})}
```

```
showExtraLine(index){
    let showExtraLine = this.state.showExtraLine.slice(0);
    showExtraLine[index] = !showExtraLine[index];
    this.setState({
       showExtraLine: showExtraLine,
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are maintaining the state for all of the mapped elements in your component, so they all reference the same value. You should instead create a component that will be used to render each of your mapped elements individually with their own state.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map((res, index) => <Child key={index} {...res} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showExtraLine: false
    };
    this.showExtraLine = this.showExtraLine.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>{this.props.testData}</span>
          <a key={index} onClick={this.showExtraLine}>
            <span className={`btn-green ${this.state.showExtraLine ? 'active' : ''}`}></span>
          </a>
          { this.state.showExtraLine ? <span>{this.props.abc[0].def}</span> : '' }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  showExtraLine(e){
    this.setState({
      showExtraLine: !this.state.showExtraLine
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not sole my problem, I need to use map here and also for 1 line I don't think I should be mKing it a separate child component

Comment: Map would still be used by the parent component. Creating a child component just cleans up your code and allows you to maintain a separate visible state for each element in your data array.